# How to properly move weblinks from my browser to a folder via drag and drop in Debian with KDE? (page titles not shown)

Tags: debian, kde, url, dolphin

Besides having my [desktop span over multiple monitors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382267/how-to-have-a-desktop-folder-view-span-not-duplicate-over-multiple-monitors) I'd also like to be able to move weblinks to it (or to folders on it).

I'm running Debian 9.1 with KDE and am using the standard Dolphin file-manager. My desktop is set to folder-view. When moving links onto it or into folders on it I get a menu showing the options "Move here", "Copy here", "Link here" and "Cancel". When I choose "Link here" I get a clickable weblink. However its name is not the page title but only the url as can be seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

I need them to be named after the page-title. Additionally, if possible I'd like to have it create a link automatically without me having to choose "Link here". Furthermore it would be nice if the link was moved into a folder on the desktop if dropped onto one (not just if it's openend with the file-manager). I'd like to keep Dolphin and KDE because otherwise they were great choices. Is this possible somehow?